# Building a form with inline editing

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Let's say we have rendered the following template which represents a `book`:

```
<div class="book">
    <h1 class="book__title" ref="title">{{book.title}}</h1>
    <p class="book__description">{{book.description}}</p>
    <button @click="activateEditMode">Edit Book</button>
</div>
```

I would like to allow my users to quickly edit this book. When users click the `Edit Book` button, they should be able to edit inline. It is as if the `.book` card is replaced by a form. It is similar to how Facebook allow its users to edit comments inline.

I have tried replacing the `<h1>` and `<p>` elements with a corresponding `<input>` and `<textarea>` elements programatically in the `activateEditMode()` method:

```
activateEditMode() {
    let bookTitle = this.$refs.title;
    let bookTitleInput = document.createElement('input');
    // but how do we programatically attach the v-model="book.title" 
    // binding to our newly created input element here?
    bookTitleInput.value = this.book.title;
}
```

How would we attach our v-model binding to our newly created input element using JavaScript?

Is this the best approach to do this?

Comment: It seems that it would be a lot easier to add the input and text areas to the template but keep them hidden, then swap them in when you are in edit mode. That way, you can setup the v-model as you usually would.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As DMan noted, what you want could be easily achieved like so:

```
<template v-if="!editing">
  <h1>{{ book.title }}</h1>
  <p>{{ book.description }}</p>

  <button @click="editing = true">Edit</button>
</template>

<template v-else>
  <input v-model="book.title">
  <input v-model="book.description">
  
  <button @click="editing = false">Done</button>
</template>
```